# Proper location of Thymeleaf views for Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-boot

I am running a spring boot application with Thymeleaf. When I run the application through my IDE (IntelliJ) everything runs fine.
However, when I run the application through the command line (`java -jar`) the views do not resolve and I get the following error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:245)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
```

Here are my settings:

My Directory Structure

```
PROJECT-ROOT
  --src
    --main
      --java
        --controllers
          --[CLASS WITH MAIN METHOD]
        --views
          --index.html
```

My template resolver:

```
@Bean
  public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("XHTML");
    templateResolver.setPrefix("views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
    return viewResolver;
  }
```

Where should I put the views so that they can be correctly resolved when ran from a jar file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is that it depends on your build configuration. The directory "src/main/views" is not a standard resource location for any common build tool, so you would have to explicitly add it to the configuration of the tool you use to build your jar.

If I were you I would go with the flow (why be different?), and just use "src/main/resources" for classpath resources. I would also leave out the thymeleaf configuration completely and let Spring Boot handle it, putting my templates in "src/main/resources/templates".

Comment: That worked, except I had to leave the thymeleaf config in. When I removed it spring couldn't resolve it for some reason.

Comment: just so others know, I also had to change my prefex to `templates/`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out from the [Springboot documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) that the **following classpath** are used by the framework:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /public/
- /static/

It means that you can put a folder templates in any of the following directories and the views inside will be found by your application.

Example:

**The file location**

*/src/main/public/templates/index.html*

**And in the application.properties**

> spring.view.prefix: /
>
> spring.view.suffix: .html

*Note* that since you are using thymeleaf, you both need to import it in your dependencies (Maven?) and use it in your html like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
```