# Spring-Boot html in /templates don't render from command line

Tags: spring-boot

I have read several online posts about this issue, but for some reason none of those helped me solve this. I looked at the spring-boot examples and I don't think I am doing much different than those.

I am using Spring-boot 1.2.1, Thymeleaf, embedded tomcat without issue in IntelliJ.  However, when I do a "gradle clean build", move the jar file, and an application.properties file to a deploy directory.  I then start on the command with:

```
java -jar edm-0.1.0.jar

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "/loginPage", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:245)
```

I am letting spring-boot configure my site for the most part.  I am using the recommended directory structure:
[image]

I can hit the index page, and the REST calls seem to work just fine.

**UPDATE based upon feedback**:
I don't know if this is a broken jar issue, but when I extract it the structure and files appear correct.  I can run "**gradle bootRun**" from the top of my project structure just fine.  But if I deploy the jar file and run it, I get an error:

```
Task 'bootRun' not found in root project 'edm'
```

Here is my build.gradle file in case there might be an issue in it:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'maven'

idea {
    project {
        //if you want to set specific jdk and language level
        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.0.201403182114"
}

project.ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.2.1.RELEASE'
}

configurations {
    querydslapt
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'edm'
    version = '0.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    querydslapt group: 'com.mysema.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '2.8.0', classifier:   'apt-one-jar', transitive: false

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:$springBootVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.0.M1")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.0.M1")
    compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3:2.1.1.RELEASE')

    compile('com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1')

    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.4.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.4.Final")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator")

    compile("org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7")
    compile('javax.mail:mail:1.4.1')
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
    compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.3")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.5.0")
    compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1")
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1')
    compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1')

    compile("postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4")

    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }

    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spock-core'
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-beans'
        exclude group: 'org.spockframework', module: 'spring-test'
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")
    testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7+')
    testCompile("junit:junit")


    // for the anontation processor
    querydslapt group: 'com.mysema.querydsl', name: 'querydsl-jpa', version: '2.8.0', classifier: 'apt-one-jar', transitive: false
// for compiling
    compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.3.3")
    compile("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.3.3")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.0'
}
project.configurations {
    providedRuntime
    }

project.bootRepackage {
    enabled = true
    }
```

I also tried adding some thymeleaf configuration (even though I am not explicitly using Thymeleaf) to my application.properties file:

```
liquibase.changeLog=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
```

So I guess my question is, why does running the "java -jar" not let me view the webpages?

Comment: Have you configured anything in application.properties? It's probably also worth checking that the templates are actually in the jar. What happens if you run with ./gradlew bootRun?

Comment: I am unable to run "./gradlew bootRun" because I get an error "Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain". Is that the preferred way to run this type of app? But I can view the contents of the jar and confirm the /template/*.html are there.   I don't have anything configured in application.properties because I wanted Spring-Boot to handle the configuration.

Comment: So I was finally able to run "./gradlew bootRun" from the project root directory.  That appears to make the html pages render, and I don't know why.  Also, it is not picking up the application.properties file that is in the same directory as the jar file.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)? application.properties won't necessarily be found in the same directory as your application's jar file. The directory would also have to be the current directory for that to work.

Comment: I did read the documentation when I developed on 1.17, but 1.2.1 seems to work differently.  I cannot start a 1.2.1 project with java -jar, but I can with 1.17.  What I don't find is how to start my jar file when I build and deploy it with "gradle clean build" - I have a jar that I can deploy, a properties file that I will put in a subdirectory "/config".

Comment: @Andy, I have updated this question with feedback on this and my other question you commented on.  I cannot figure out if the executable jar is busted, or "java -jar" just doesn't work for me since upgrading to 1.2.1.RELEASE.  Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: Please have a look on my answer in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249078/spring-boot-gives-templateinputexception-error-resolving-template-when-runnin/42740408#42740408)

Comment: Please have a look on my answer on [Stackoverflow-Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249078/spring-boot-gives-templateinputexception-error-resolving-template-when-runnin/42740408#42740408)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my REST controllers were proceeded by "/"  so login page became "//loginPage" and that was causing the problem.  I found the answer [here](http://expertland.net/question/z5sb1c3m48s2p423ms247uub1cv5bl67/detail.html) but it took me a while to realize that was the issue.  Hopefully this answer will help out someone in the future as it as a bear to figure out.