# Spring Boot seems to be auto-generating bad paths

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am experimenting with Spring Boot and have created a simple Spring Boot webapp that *should* just expose a simple/mock homepage at `http://localhost:9200`.

Here is the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/bootup).

When I run this locally (instructions are in the README), there are no errors in the console output. However, when I point a browser at `http://localhost:9200`, I am prompted for an HTTP Basic Auth-style username + password combo (which I *definitely* did not add myself), and am never able to actually see the homepage (which is located in that repo under `src/main/resources/templates/web/index.html`).

In the console output I get this stack trace:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going awry? The stack trace doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282606/4009451) I have a duplicate forward-slash in one of my paths (`//`) but for the life of me I cannot see where!

Comment: basic authentication comes from security dependency. Are you expecting to use thymeleaf?

Comment: Thanks @jny (+1) - I removed the security dependency and the basic auth dialog went away - thanks for the help there! However, when I go to `http://localhost:9200` I am still getting a blank screen and the same error in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WebController` class has a wrong package definition - `com.surancehub.controllers`, should be `hotmeatballsoup.bootup.controllers` in order to be picked up by Boot

Comment: Thanks @Milos! Good catch! Wonder why that didn't get picked up during compilation and only reared its head when processing templates...

Comment: Well, I blame Groovy's dynamic sneakiness :D